# How to customize closing options of Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1

I am using windows 8.1.

[image]

I would like to customize options on the image. Shut down is defaut option in this window. I would like to change default option as hibernate. I would like two options to be in this window, restart and hibernate.

What can I do that ?

Comment: This is handled by a group policy.  I was able to find the following source ( http://www.classicshell.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=918 ) without a great deal of research.  Since the question is well written I won't issue a downvote.  I won't punish this good question because my Google-fu is better then yours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Windows 7 the default can be changed from the Start Menu tab of the taskbar properties.  It appears that with Windows 8.0, Microsoft moved this behavior to a group policy, I conclude that based on the following information.

> On Windows 8, the Group Policy setting works. Gpedit.msc -> User
>   Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> Start Menu and Taskbar ->
>   Change Start Menu power button.

[Source](http://www.classicshell.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=918)

Comment: Thank you for answer. I have set hibernate as default. However I couldn't remove other options are switch user, sign out and shutdown.

Comment: @sinanakyazici - You won't be able to get rid of the ability to switch to a different user, sign out of a specific user, nor shutdown your computer.  Those are basic functions of Windows, even a Guest, is able to shutdown ( or perhaps restart it ) and switch which user is logged in.